# NDepend -Finding dead methods

Tags: ndepend, cqlinq

I have two public methods A & B. I modified CQL to show me methods which are public and dead.

If B is only called by A and A is coming as dead method(not called or referenced anywhere in the application) can NDepend show both the methods as dead by doing some settings or by CQL?

In current scenario I am getting only A as dead method not B.

Answer (score 2):

> can NDepend show both the methods as dead by doing some settings or by CQL?

Yes, [NDepend](http://www.NDepend.com) can do that thanks to [Code Rule over LINQ Query (CQLinq)](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL) capabilities.

Around [200 default code rules](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html) are proposed, 3 of them being dedicated to *unused/dead code* detection:

- [Potentially dead Types](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Potentially_dead_Types.html) (hence detect unused class, struct, interface, delegate...)
- [Potentially dead Methods](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Potentially_dead_Methods.html) (hence detect unused method, ctor, property getter/setter...)
- [Potentially dead Fields](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Potentially_dead_Fields.html)

If you click these 3 links above toward the source code of these rules, you'll see that the ones concerning types and methods are a bit complex. This is because **these rules detect not only unused types and methods, but also types and methods used *only* by unused dead types and methods (recursive, what you are asking for).**